# Compare two collections & get the missed user id documents

Tags: mongodb, collections, compare, aggregate, lookup

I have two collections Payment & Wallet. Whenever the user make some payment then this payment information get inserted in Payment collection and further wallet collection also get inserted. Wallet collection has Payment Id & User Id as foreign key.

For 100 transactions any one or two wallet insertions are not happening.

I'm trying to get the missed wallet insertions by comparing two collections. I started with the following query and changing this multiple ways to get the desired output.

```
const missedPayment = await Payment
        .aggregate([
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "Wallet",
              localField: "_id",
              foreignField: "paymentId",
              as: "missedWallet"
            }
          }
        ])
        .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
```

All I need is to get the documents inserted in Payment Collection but not in Wallet Collection. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query to find the documents inserted in Payment Collection but not in Wallet Collection:

```
db.Payment.aggregate([
{"$match":{"_id":{"$exists":1}}},
{"$lookup":{"from": "Wallet",
            "localField":"_id",
            "foreignField":"paymentId",
            "as":"missedWallet"
}},
{"$match":{"missedWallet.0":{"$exists":0}}}
],{"allowDiskUse":true});
```

Comment: Payment.aggregate([{ $match: { userId: user._id } } It works after I changed like this. Thanks for the answer.